# Rails routing format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, format, routes

I am trying to build a one page application and having trouble with Rails routing. Basically I want everything within admin route to admin controller index but json rails to specific resource. I've tried

```
namespace :admin do
  constraints :format => 'html' do
    match '*path' => 'admin#index'
  end

  constraints :format => 'json' do
      resources :user, :items
  end
end
```

In this case path will match greedily and match /admin/users.json
If I move the :format => 'json' block up. It matches /admin/users

Looks like the constraints blocks I specify does not works at all.

Rails version 3.2.6
rake routes

```
/admin/*path(.:format)                        admin/admin#index {:format=>"html"}
admin_users GET    /admin/users(.:format)     admin/users#index {:format=>"json"}
```

/* other normal resources routes for admin users and admin items */

I have checked and there is no route /admin/users(.format)  admin/users#index {:format=>"html"}

so looks like it is exactly what I think it would be. but somehow still does not works

**Update:**
I have managed to get it workings if it move the json block up
However if the html block is on top. It is still causing me problem. But I think it is good enough for me now. Thanks guys

The original problem is I used request.xhr? in the controller where I should have used respond_to

**Update 2**
Uhm not acutally working now when I go to /admin/users I got a Not acceptable error. Where I would think that the first rule wont be match and match the second rule.

Comment: Not sure why this does not work, but you might want to try creating your own constraints class, and check for the request format yourself...

Comment: rails version? $rake routes result?

Comment: /admin/*path(.:format)               admin/admin#index {:format=>"html"}

    admin_users GET    /admin/users(.:format)            admin/users#index {:format=>"json"}

    ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it work if you move the json block up and make the format segment mandatory for each json resource? In Rails 3.2 this happens by setting the **format** option to **true**:

```
namespace :admin do
  constraints(format: "json") do
    resources :items, format: true
    resources :users, format: true
  end

  constraints(format: "html") do
    match "*path" => "admin#index"
  end
end
```